# Getting 'too many open files' error when inserting documents in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

I am creating a largish (80k collections, 200k documents per collection) database in Mongo. When I start pushing documents into the database, I keep getting the following error after ~800k inserts.

```
pymongo.errors.WriteError: 24: Too many open files
```

I have a decent sized server (2 vCPU, 32 GB RAM). `ulimit` for file open is set to unlimited. And `limit nofile 999999 999999` is set in /etc/init/mongodb.conf.

I have tried inserting `sleep` (with the hope that mongodb will close files after a bit) in the file insertion script but that hasn't helped either. The only thing that works is restarting Mongodb after the insertion has failed. Then the process can resume.

How can I make insertion process better without having to pause it after every few thousand inserts and restarting mongodb?

---

Sharing the Python script that is transferring datapoint from redis to mongo

```
while (redis_conn.llen(redis_key) > 0) :
            redis_json = redis_conn.lpop(redis_key)
            json_doc = json.loads(redis_point)
            collection_name = json_doc['collection_name']
            collection = mongodb[collection_name]
            document = { '1' : json_doc['1'], '2' : json_doc['2'] }
            mongo_write_response = collection.insert_one(document)
```

(For brevity I have simplified the document. The actual document has around 20 data points.

Comment: if it's related to your code, maybe you could show it.

Comment: What version of mongodb? And are you using `mmapv1` or `wiredTiger`?

Comment: @RobertSeaman - v3.4 with WT ... Also added part of code to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the installation of MongoDB. I was using Debian 9 and used `apt-get` to install the version of MongoDB that ships bundled with the OS.

Since MongoDB documentation said it does not support Debian 9 yet, downgraded the OS to Debian 8 and installed MongoDB community edition as per the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/). It is working well now :)